# jQuery is unable to find an element by it's Id even though it exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem where jQuery seems to be unable to find an element by it's Id even though it exists and I can't seem to find any issues.

The page lists projects, with each project being wrapped in a div with a unique Id. On each project there's a button, when clicked it should run a function which scrolls the page down to the next project.

Example HTML is this, it lists two projects, both of which are loaded from database and dynamically generated by PHP to generate static HTML (not loaded via Ajax, which I know would require referencing the element a different way).

```
<div id="project-24" class="project-item" data-this="#project-24" data-next="#project-25">
    <!-- Start: Main Slideshow -->
    <section id="slideshow" class="project-slideshow first">
        <div class="flexslider flexslider-slideshow">
            <ul class="slides">
            </ul>
        </div> 
    </section>
    <!-- End: Main Slideshow -->

    <!-- Start: Project details -->
    <section class="general project-detail" id="project-24-text">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="with-line"><span>. Travel Alphabet .</span></h1>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                        <p>Project Details here</p>

                        <p class="button"><a class="scrollable" href="#portfolio-25">Next &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>        
    </section>
    <!-- End: Project details -->
</div>

 <div id="project-25" class="project-item" data-this="#project-25" data-next="#project-26">
    <!-- Start: Main Slideshow -->
    <section id="slideshow" class="project-slideshow first">
        <div class="flexslider flexslider-slideshow">
            <ul class="slides">
            </ul>
        </div> 
    </section>
    <!-- End: Main Slideshow -->

    <!-- Start: Project details -->
    <section class="general project-detail" id="project-24-text">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="with-line"><span>. Travel Alphabet .</span></h1>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                        <p>Project Details here</p>

                        <p class="button"><a class="scrollable" href="#portfolio-25">Next &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>        
    </section>
    <!-- End: Project details -->
</div>
```

When the next button is clicked, it's picked up by some jQuery and actioned;

```
function scrollToAnchor(id){
    var header = $('header');
    var tag = $(id);

    var pos = tag.offset().top - header.outerHeight();

    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: pos}, 'fast');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.scrollable').click(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        scrollToAnchor(href);

        return false;
    });
});
```

When I view the page and click the button, jQuery gives the following error;

> script.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of
>   undefined

I've tried to amend the scrollToAnchor method to the following, and it seems to confirm that the element isn't found as 'not found' is displayed in the console;

```
function scrollToAnchor(id){
    var header = $('header');
    var tag = $('body').find(id);

    console.log("looking for " + id);

    if (tag.length) {
        console.log(id + " found");
    } else {
        console.log(id + " not found");
    }

    var pos = tag.offset().top - header.outerHeight();

    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: pos},'fast');
}
```

Comment: I can't find the element portfolio-25 in the HTML you posted, so that error would be obvious. Were you looking for "#project-25" instead?

Comment: As said above, there's no `#portfolio-25` element in your HTML. However there is a `#project-25`, did you mean that instead?

Comment: Yes, it's one of those days where no matter how hard you look you can't spot the obvious problem. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood, but if you are trying to link to a section within the page, you don't need JQuery, or JavaScript for that matter at all.

E.g.:

```html
<div>
  <section id="section-1">
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#section-2">Next</a>
  </section>
  
  <section id="section-2">
    <h1>Section 2</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#section-3">Next</a>
  </section>
  
  <section id="section-3">
    <h1>Section 3</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#section-4">Next</a>
  </section>
  
  <section id="section-4">
    <h1>Section 4</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#section-1">To top</a>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not just a case of linking to the next project in the list, when the next button is clicked the client wants the page to scroll down to the next project, I don't mean 'jump' to the next project I mean an animated 'scroll', hence the use of jQuery to handle this.

Comment: In that case you just need to correct the IDs, as  they seem to use project whereas the anchor tags point to portfolio.

Answer (score 0):

your code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.scrollable').click(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        scrollToAnchor(href);

        return false;
    });
});
```

will return you the href of a which is #portfolio-25 try replacing this with your div id.

... Edit ....

Instead of this

```
 <p class="button"><a class="scrollable" href="#portfolio-25">Next &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a></p>
```

you can have simple button

```
<input type = 'button' class = 'scrollable' name = 'project-25' /> <i class = 'fa fa-angle-down'></i> Next
```

and into your JS function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.scrollable').click(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('name');
        scrollToAnchor(href);

        return false;
    });
});
```

Please consider editing your button as per your requirement, this is just for example.

Comment: which error? obviously its not good to refer ID into a tag property and read it through, but with least alteration to his code as he prefer it to be hardcoaded.

Comment: The link on the button has a href of #project-25, the idea is that when the button is clicked, we get the value of the href as this tells us which project is next in the list. We pass the value of href over to the scrollToAnchor function which should then use the value of href to locate a div#project-25 and then animate the scroll to that id.

Comment: I can see you have portfolio-25 written into this code  <p class="button"><a class="scrollable" href="#portfolio-25">Next &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a></p>

Comment: also if you are giving a button why do you need anchor tag, you can directly use button and refer its name instead...